# How can I change a cell of a DataGrid depending on the data it is bound to using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, mvvm-light

I'm using the MVVM Light Toolkit and I have a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection. There is only one text column displayed. I'd like the text of the cell to be Bold or Normal depending on a boolean that is inside the object displayed. I figured I could use RelayCommands but they only take 1 parameter and I need at least 2 to get the CellContent (the DataGridRowEventArgs and the DataGrid itself). I tried to fire a RelayCommand Execute delegate on "LoadingRow" event but with only one parameter I couldn't do it.

Here is the DataGrid in the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="112,34,0,8" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentNewsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" MinWidth="92" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="{Binding CurrentNewsList[0].MyFont}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NewsSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=dataGrid1}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

I set the grid in Blend. Notice that the FontWeight is bound like "{Binding CurrentNewsList[0].MyFont}". Is it right ? I also tried "{Binding MyFont}" but both got the same result: No BOld :(

MyFont is set in the Object constructor with a boolean:

```
MyFont = newIsRead ? FontWeights.Normal : FontWeights.Bold;
```

Please help.

Thx

Comment: Does the boolean value change, and need to update the font style, or is it always either bold / normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use an implicit style and a trigger:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolean}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

*(If you ever have more columns you could just use the styles on the column (`ElementStyle` & `ElementEditingStyle`) instead to limit the effect)*

Comment: I never used these. I'll look into it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: I finally managed to make it using your solution. Thank you !

Comment: Now I have to do it in Silverlight and Style.Triggers aren't there !! What is the alternative ? I might ask a new question for this.

Comment: @DEIONaLiMs: You could bind the `FontWeight` directly to you bool and apply a `Converter` in the binding.

Comment: I did that already. Not with the bool and the Converter though, with a Direct FontWeight just like I explained in the question. Do I have to go through a converter to make it work ?

Comment: Actually, I can't bind the FontWeight property to any parameter as I have a XmlParseException raised by System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn.FontWeight.

Comment: @DEIONaLiMs: I also would have suggested using the Interactivity DataTrigger, if you want the value to return to the default you will need another DataTrigger on the same binding and the same value but the `Comparison` set to `NotEqual`, in that trigger you need to set the value back to the default.

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286666/how-can-i-change-a-cell-of-a-datagrid-depending-on-the-data-it-is-bound-to-using/8288442#8288442) . Thank you again :)

Comment: @DEIONaLiMs: I was referring to that post when i said "I also...".

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like that, I generally create a "model object" that is specifically for binding.  So, instead of binding to an observable collection of "Customer", you bind to an observable collection of "CustomerModel", where the model object has a "CustomerName" property and then some other property that corresponds to the desired font (either an actual Font object, or some kind of enumeration that you parse via a value converter, if you don't want your VM layer knowing about view concerns).  This model object could figure out what to make available depending on the boolean property you mention.

Comment: I tried this approch but the Font is never set to Bold. I bound the FontWeight this way: FontWeight="{Binding MyFont}" where MyFont is a FontWeight set to FontWeights.Normal or FontWeights.Bold depending on the boolean in the constructor. Am I suppose to raise some PropertyCahngedEvent ?

Comment: Yes, whenever you change the font weight in the bound object, you would want to raise property changed event to notify the GUI.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know what I do wrong. When I put a breakpoint, I can see that the grid requests the "CustomerName" property as it goes through the getter of it. But it doesn't go through the MyFont getter.

Comment: Maybe update your question so that we can have a look at your XAML and relevant code behind...

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I get back from work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer (although not thoroughly explained)

Comment: I updated the question. Can you see anything that is not set right ? If not, d'you guys have a sample code that explains how to do it ? Thx

Comment: I managed to make it using the solution above. Thank you very much for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed to make it using H.B solution:

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRead}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Style1}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```