# How can I change a cell of a DataGrid depending on the data it is bound to using MVVM in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, expression-blend

I recently posted the same question but for WPF and got an answer. The thing is that answer doesn't work in Silverlight. 
Here is the situation: I'm using the MVVM Light Toolkit and I have a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection. There is only one text column displayed. I'd like the text of the cell to be Bold or Normal depending on a boolean that is inside the object displayed. 
To make it work in WCF i used a Style with a Syle.Trigger:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRead}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Style1}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The problem is that this is not available in Silverlight. I made some research and found that VisualStateManager is the "replacement" for triggers but I never managed to create a state that edits the DataGridTextColumn. I tried a bunch of different ways from GoToState to DataStateBehavior... nothing worked so far.

Please Help !

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FontWeight` property doesn't work well with the `DataGridTextColumn` column type. So you should change this column to the `DataGridTemplateColumn` type with the `TextBlock` control inside and apply the expression blend data trigger to it.

Here is the code:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ic:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsRead}" Value="False">
                        <ic:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="FontWeight" >
                            <ic:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                            </ic:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                        </ic:ChangePropertyAction>
                    </ic:DataTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The namespaces `i` and `ic` are defined so:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

The necessary libraries become available when you install Expression Blend SDK.

If you don't have the SDK, you can use the alternative approach and write a value converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    FontWeight="{Binding IsRead, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToFontWeightConverter}}" />
```

Comment: It works !! Thank you !! I added a 2nd DataTrigger for the value "True" of IsRead and Normal for the FontWeight so that it goes back to normal when the bool changes to true. I find it weird though that "The FontWeight property doesn't work well with the DataGridTextColumn column type". For me text and font are bro and sis :). Thank you again you've been a great help.